# C# - operator overloading through inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, operator-overloading, mutation-testing

I am trying to come up with the way to implement a way to perform a Mutation test on my class (yes I am aware of Stryker .NET).

For the sake of simplicity, let's say that I want to write a Mutator class that some service will inherit from, and it will convert all additions to subtraction. I am wondering whether it is possible to achieve this without doing any changes to the service class.

I have this service that performs a simple addition

```
public class Service : Mutator
{

    public int AddTwoNumbers(int firstNum, int secondNum)
    {
        return firstNum + secondNum;
    }
}
```

at first, I simply tried to write Mutator class as follows:

```
 public class Mutator
 {
     public static int operator +(int a, int b)
     {
         return a - b;
     }
 }
```

but of course quickly discovered that following code produces compiler error ("One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type")

So I wonder, if there is a way to achieve this kind of mutation trough inheritance without changing the actual Service class.

The reason I choose operator overloading instead of method overloading or something like that is because I want to be able to inherit from this Mutator from any random class and to just simply change all + into -

Answer (score 1):

It tells you that one of the operator params need to be the type of the overloading class itself. The `operator+` overload must have a param of type `Mutator`.

What you want to do is inherently impossible for all types because:

1. Any type could implement subtraction however they want,
2. There are no guarantees that the + and - operators were overloaded by a type in the first place, and
3. Operator overloads must have a parameter that matches the type overloading them.

However, it is possible to achieve this to *some* degree. You can implement Mutator to be generic and add constraints to it so you *know* that a derived type will have an addition or subtraction that you can swap. You will not be able to use generic `T` as params alone, though. Mutator will have to be a wrapper class. Here is an example:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var origin = new Mutator<long>(10L);
    var x = origin + 3; // 7
    var y = origin - 3; // 13

    Console.WriteLine($"origin: {origin.Value}");
    Console.WriteLine($"x: {x}");
    Console.WriteLine($"y: {y}");
}

class Mutator<T>(T value)
    where T : IAdditionOperators<T, T, T>, ISubtractionOperators<T, T, T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; } = value;

    public static T operator +(Mutator<T> x, T y)
        => x.Value - y;

    public static T operator -(Mutator<T> x, T y)
        => x.Value + y;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking your time to answer.
I used int for the sake of simplicity, and my Mutator class is a lot like yours, however I was wondering if there was a way to overload all the methods inside of the class that inherits from the Mutator, so instead of 
```
var origin = new Mutator<long>(10L);
    var x = origin + 3; // 7
    var y = origin - 3; // 13
```
I would have 

```
int firstNum = 5;
int secondNum = 6;

var add = new Service.AddTwoNumbers(firstNum, secondNum); // -1
```

Comment: @MaoShengelia No it's not possible to do it for another class that you didn't implement. What you likely want is a wrapper struct/class for what you want that overloads operators and just does what you want on its wrapped value